# Datatables responsive column priority

Tags: datatables

I have a datatable with 10 columns on a large screen, but would like priority to be given to the first and last columns when the screen is resized:

```
<div class="card mb-3">
<div class="card-header">
  <i class="fa fa-table"></i> Client Database</div>
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-priority="1">Address</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Joining Date</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>DB Serial</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Contract Payments</th>
          <th>Battery Reserve</th>
          <th data-priority="2">Action</th>
        </tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
    } );
} );
</script>

<script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/b-1.4.2/r-2.2.0/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/b-1.4.2/r-2.2.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

However, the columns are still not responsive:
[image]

Comment: Three things: 1) why are you adding twice the `class` selector? 2) if you have included from local `jquery.dataTables.js` why are you including it again from cdn? 3) your snipet code doesn't seem to be complete or even valid.

Answer (score 0):

Learn through this example:

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/auto.html

You have to add the plugin and put `responsive` class onto the table

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is really old, but the reason the table is not acting responsively is due to using Bootstrap's `.table-responsive` class (and wrapping the table with a DIV) - this enables Bootstrap's solution for responsive tables, but DataTables requires a `.responsive` class on the `table` element (and the responsive plug-in for DT) to be implemented for *its* version of responsive tables.